# How to "release" the X Axis after calling chart.zoom()?

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I set the scroll strategy to `setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.progressive)` and on page loaded the chart is scrolling very fast because my data is coming in fast. However I worked around by setting a certain zoom on start up to the chart using `chart.zoom({ x: -200, y: 180 }, { x: 500, y: 500 })` then again the chart doesnt auto scroll along the X axis anymore, what function do I invoke to release the axis without having to double click on the X axis?

Another question is that I dont understand how the data cleaning, at first I expected `series.setDataCleaning({ minDataPointCount: 1000 })` to clean up the data points that went past 1000 and out of view but I `console.log(series.getPointAmount())` I noticed the total points going past 1000 I left it running for awhile and it still doesnt clean up? I calculated the total duration of data I want on my timeseries chart and it comes down to 120k data points, what should I do to ensure there's always minimum 120k points on the chart while cleaning up old ones that I dont need to be rendered?

Answer (score 0):

In setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.progressive):--  axis will keep distance between start and end constant, and scroll to reveal series boundaries that go higher than active axis interval.

But you can use setInterval property of Axis to manually set it's interval so that it doesn't load fast.

```
Axis.setInterval(0, 100)
```

You can also pass some other parameters in setInterval like :-

disableScrolling: If true, disables automatic scrolling after setting interval

animate:Boolean for animation enabled, or number for animation duration in milliseconds

```
setInterval(start: number, end: number, animate: number | boolean | undefined, disableScrolling: boolean | undefined): this
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I think you misunderstood the behaviour I wanted, I want it to work like the default auto scroll but after the chart.zoom() call, the user has to double click on to the X axis to enable auto scroll again, I want to perform this action programmatically, so that the user doesnt need to double click the X axis.